# 404 not found twitter api 1.1 codeginter

Tags: codeigniter, twitter, http-status-code-404, getjson, dashboard

I've been working on upgrading from v 1 to 1.1 for a few days now. I have 100s of users that can't see their followers in my dashboard.
I followed all the steps by changing /1/ to /1.1/ still not working.

Getting error 404 (Not Found)
Controller:

```
 function twitter_auth()
  {

 if ( !$this->tweet->logged_in() )
 {
 die('some how you are not logged in');
 }

 $tokens = $this->tweet->get_tokens();

 $this->tweet->enable_debug(TRUE);

 $user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');
 var_dump($user);

 }

 $options = array(
  'count' => 10,
  'page' => 2,
  'include_entities' => 1
  );

  $timeline = $this->tweet->call('get', 'statuses/home_timeline');

 var_dump($timeline);
 }
```

Jobs:

```
 function get_twitter_subscribers($args)
 {
  $rate = @file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json');
  $rate = @json_decode($rate);

  if($rate->remaining_hits == 0):
  $status = 'retask';
 else:

  $new_data = @file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?  screen_name='.$args['account_id'].'&include_entities=true');
  $new_data = @json_decode($new_data);
  if(isset($new_data->followers_count)){

  $insert_args = array(
  'account_id' => $args['account_id'],
  'metric' => 'subscribers',
  'value' => $new_data->followers_count,
  'platform' => 'twitter'
   );

   $insert = $this->CI->metrics_model->insert_metric($insert_args);

   if (isset($insert)) { $status = 'complete'; }

    }else{
     $this->send_error_email("Function: get_twitter_subscribers - new_data->followers_count not set for account id: " . $args['account_id'] . "\r\n\r\n" . "args: " . http_build_query($args) . "\r\n\r\n" . 'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$args['account_id'].'&include_entities=true');
    }

  endif;

   if(!isset($status)){
   $this->send_error_email("Function: get_twitter_subscribers - status not set." . "\r\n\r\n" . "args: " . http_build_query($args) . "\r\n\r\n" .   'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?    screen_name='.$args['account_id'].'&include_entities=true');
   $status = 'error';
   }

   return $status;
```

controllers:

```
   function auth($platform)
   {

   if($platform == 'facebook'):
   echo 'auth facebook';
   elseif($platform == 'twitter'):

   $this->load->library('tweet');

   // current key in php page
   $tokens = array(
   'oauth_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   'oauth_token_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
   );

   $this->tweet->set_tokens($tokens);

   if ( !$this->tweet->logged_in() ) :
   $this->tweet->set_callback(site_url('manage/auth/twitter'));
   $this->tweet->login();
   else:
   echo 'Twitter logged in. <a href="/manage/">Return to manager</a>';
  endif;

  endif;

  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which twitterApi library you are using ? maybe you need to upgrade it too. In v 1.1, you can't do just `$new_data = @file_get_contents('http://api.twitter...`, you need authorisation whatever you do.

Comment: this was a custom built app, codeigniter. The auth_token and oauth_toaken_secret username and password is stored in a database.  All was working ok until the upgrade to twitter api 1.1.  I didn't change anything else.   $new_data = @file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.. This worked fine in twitter api version 1, it changed in 1.1, I must be missing something small, i checked all over twitter help docs, nothing.

Comment: this: `$this->load->library('tweet')` , you create `tweet` library by yourself ? like I said, in twitter API v1.1, you need an authorization to get everything.

Comment: It was created by a previous developer, okay let me check back with dev twitter on this topic to get instructions on how to do that.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api You need to contact the previous developer. :D

Comment: Forgot to mention this is a dashboard, it doesn't capture streaming tweets just statistics of 312 twitter accounts, # of followers and total followers overtime.  That's it. It doesn't use 1 particular  twitter user account.  But I did see klout account in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved.  I created my own cURL library.

```
 function get_twitter_subscribers($args){
    $request = curl_init();
    $bearer = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJ%2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0000x0x0x0x0"; 
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$args['account_id'].'&include_entities=true');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$bearer));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $new_data = json_decode($file_get_contents = curl_exec($request)); 
    curl_close($request);

    if(isset($new_data->followers_count)){
        $insert_args = array(
        'account_id' => $args['account_id'],
        'metric' => 'subscribers',
        'value' => $new_data->followers_count,
        'platform' => 'twitter'
        );

        $insert = $this->CI->metrics_model->insert_metric($insert_args);
    if (isset($insert)) { $status = 'complete'; }
        }else{
        $this->send_error_email("Function: get_twitter_subscribers - new_data->followers_count not set for account id: " . $args['account_id'] . "\r\n\r\n" . "args: " . http_build_query($args) . "\r\n\r\n" . 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$args['account_id'].'&include_entities=true');   
    }

  if(!isset($status)){
    $this->send_error_email("Function: get_twitter_subscribers - status not set." . "\r\n\r\n" . "args: " . http_build_query($args) . "\r\n\r\n" . 'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$args['account_id'].'&include_entities=true');
$status = 'error';
}

   return $status;
}
```